# Accessing gem functions from controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a [bitcoin-ruby](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby) in gemfile, how do I access the following from my rails controller?

```
key = Bitcoin::generate_key
@address = Bitcoin::pubkey_to_address(key[1])
```

Error:

```
uninitialized constant HomeController::Bitcoin
```

Gemfile:

```
gem "bitcoin-ruby", "~> 0.0.4"
```

I tried to do this in plain ruby, (installing bitcoin-ruby was successful)

```
require 'bitcoin-ruby'
```

Throws up the following error.

```
/home/p4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- bitcoin-ruby (LoadError)
from /home/p4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from bitcoin.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Probably it is due to my lack of understanding of linking ruby libraries, where am I wrong?

Comment: Your approach is correct, but you have typo in second line, it should be `Bitcoin::pubkey_to_address(key[1])`.

Comment: I did not cp/paste the code, but I din't have any typo in my actual source.

Comment: So, please show me your `Gemfile`.

Comment: updated with the gemfile of bitcoin-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the README you need to add a require key:

```
gem "bitcoin-ruby", "~> 0.0.4", require: 'bitcoin'
```

Comment: @Ernest that solved the issue, better head to the README you mentioned about.